# Ruby on rails query issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am developing web application on rails4.

I have user, block and request tables.
Block has blocker_id and blocked_id.
Some users have requests and some users can block other users.

I want to get some request entity that is created by some user and not blocked another user.

Assume there is r1 that is created by u1.
u2 wants to get r1 if u2 not blocks u1.

like Request.where("requests.user_id not blocked by u2")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the relations you have set up for the 3 models, it's a little hard to give a complete response.  The following is one scenario.

You're trying to determine whether or not to display a request from a user.
This depends on whether or not the logged in User (lets call them `current_user`) has blocked the requesting user (lets call them `requestor`).  A blocked user can be found in the Blocked table.

You could first query the Block table to see if the user has been blocked:

```
Block.find_by(blocked_id: requestor.id, blocker_id: current_user.id)
```

That will return a Block object if one is found, otherwise it will return `nil`.  Setting that to a variable will now give a user's blocked status.  Probably best set in the controller action.

```
class RequestsController << ApplicationController

  def show
    @blocked_status = Block.find_by(blocked_id: requestor.id, blocker_id: current_user.id)
    @request = Request.find_by(request_from_id: requestor.id, request_to_id: current_user.id)
  end
end
```

Then you could use that information in your view to either display the request or not

in `requests.html.erb`

```
<% unless @blocked_status %>
   # html to display request from requestor to current_user
<% end %>
```

Or

use a scope to find the request with something like:

```
scope :not_blocked_by, -> (user_id) {
   joins("JOIN `blocks` b ON b.`blocked_id` = `requests`.`request_from_id` AND b.`blocker_id` = #{current_user.id}")
   .where.not('b.blocked_id = :user_id', user_id: user_id)
}
```

then in the controller.

```
class RequestsController << ApplicationController

  def show
    @request = Request.not_blocked_by(@requestor.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for reply, what i wanted to do is Request.where(Block.where(:blocker_id => current_user.id, :blocked_id => requests.user_id).exists.not) how can i do that?

Comment: I would use a scope to take care of everything after 'Request'.  You'll need to create a query in the scope that joins Block, it would look similar to the scope I wrote above, but you'll need to change it a little it if you still want to use `.exists?`.  Try the [Rails API Guide on Scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) for some more detail and examples on scopes.